# UNIT Test Error: No Contract deployed with name Raffle

Tags: solidity, javascript, testing

This is the section of my unit testing... I've been working on this problem for the last few hours. I couldn't, however... I think the error is in `const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()` this line. Raffle contract isn't recognized...
(Note- All the deployments are working correctly... )

```
 !developmentChains.includes(network.name)
        ? describe.skip()
        : describe("Raffle UNIT test", async () => {
              let raffle, vrfCoordinatorV2Mock
              const chainId = network.config.chainId
              beforeEach(async () => {
                  const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()
                  await deployments.fixture(["all"])
                  raffle = await ethers.getContract("Raffle", deployer)
                  vrfCoordinatorV2Mock = await ethers.getContract("VRFCoordinatorV2Mock", deployer)
              })
              describe("Constructor function", async () => {
                  it("Initializes the raffle correctly.", async () => {
                      const raffleState = await raffle.getRaffleState()
                      const interval = await raffle.getInterval()
    
                      assert.equal(raffleState.toString(), "0")
                      assert.equal(interval.toString(), networkConfig[chainId]["interval"])
                  })
              })
          })
```

ERROR that I've got...

```
~/b/JSweb3_2/smart-contract_lottery  on main !2  hh test                                                      ✔  took 5s  system    at 07:27:25 am 


  Raffle UNIT test
    Constructor function
Development chain detected! Deploying mocks
Mocks deployed!!!...
---------------------!--!--!---------------------
      1) "before each" hook for "Initializes the raffle correctly."
  0 passing (428ms)
  1 failing

  1) Raffle UNIT test
       "before each" hook for "Initialises the raffle correctly.":
     Error: No Contract deployed with name Raffle
      at Object.getContract (node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/src/internal/helpers.ts:447:11)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
      at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:65:3)
      at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:528:9)
      at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/unit/Raffle.test.js:16:24)
```

I AM FOLLOWING A CORDING TUTOTIAL.

**Edit - deploy script**

```
const { network, ethers } = require("hardhat")
const { developmentChains, networkConfig } = require("../helper-hardhat-config")
const { verify } = require("../utils/verify")

module.exports = async ({ getNamedAccounts, deployments }) => {
    const { deploy, log } = deployments
    const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()
    let VRFCoordinatorV2Address, subscriptionId
    const chainId = network.config.chainId
    const VRF_SUB_FUND_AMOUNT = ethers.utils.parseEther("30")

    if (developmentChains.includes(network.name)) {
        const VRFCoordinatorV2Mock = await ethers.getContract("VRFCoordinatorV2Mock")
        VRFCoordinatorV2Address = VRFCoordinatorV2Mock.address

        const transactionResponse = await VRFCoordinatorV2Mock.createSubscription()
        const transactionReceipt = await transactionResponse.wait(1)
        subscriptionId = transactionReceipt.events[0].args.subId
        // fund the subscription
        await VRFCoordinatorV2Mock.fundSubscription(subscriptionId, VRF_SUB_FUND_AMOUNT)
    } else {
        VRFCoordinatorV2Address = networkConfig[chainId]["vrfCoordinatorV2"]
        subscriptionId = networkConfig[chainId]["subscriptionId"]
    }

    const entranceFee = networkConfig[chainId]["entranceFee"]
    const gasLane = networkConfig[chainId]["gasLane"]
    const callBackGasLimit = networkConfig[chainId]["callBackGasLimit"]
    const interval = networkConfig[chainId]["interval"]
    const args = [
        VRFCoordinatorV2Address,
        entranceFee,
        gasLane,
        subscriptionId,
        callBackGasLimit,
        interval,
    ]

    const raffle = await deploy("Raffle", {
        from: deployer,
        args: args,
        log: true,
        waitConfirmations: network.config.blockConfirmations || 1,
    })

    if (!developmentChains.includes(network.name) && process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY) {
        log("Verifying...")
        await verify(raffle.address, args)
    }
    log("-----------!!!!!------!!!!!---!!!!!-----!!!!!----------")

    module.exports.tags = ["all", "raffle"]
}
```

Comment: Where is the code that actually deploys the contract?  
Which tutorial are you following?

Comment: @ruby_newbie I have updated the deploy script and the tutorial is PatricAlphaC's eth BootCamp... [link] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gyMwXuJrbJQ&t=730s)

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.The error was,
This line `module.exports.tags = ['all', 'mocks'];` was inside the deploy script's curly brackets...